# Hide woocommerce storefront handheld footer on cart, checkout, and account

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I am trying to hide the Storefront handheld footer bar on the cart, footer, and account pages. I am new to coding in Wordpress and Woocommerce and coded the following and nothing works. Below are my 3 attempts what am I doing wrong? Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

```
add_action('wp_head','noshowHHFCSS');
function noshowHHFCSS() {
echo '<style>
/* Do not show hand held footer bar on cart, check out and account page*/
.page-id-5 .page-id-6 .page-id-7 .storefront-handheld-footer-bar  {
display: none!important;
}
</style>';
} 


if ( is_cart() || is_checkout() || is_account_page() ) { 
echo '<style>
/* Do not show hand held footer bar on cart, check out and account page*/
.storefront-handheld-footer-bar  {
display: none!important;
}
</style>';
} 


add_action( 'init', 'jk_remove_storefront_handheld_footer_bar' );
if ( is_cart() || is_checkout() || is_account_page() ) {
function jk_remove_storefront_handheld_footer_bar() {
remove_action( 'storefront_footer', 'storefront_handheld_footer_bar', 999 );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:
Create in your root theme folder a new folder called CSS if you don't have one already. After that create a `customFooterStyle.css` file with your footer style code in it.

In the `function.php` place this code:

```
function footerBarStyle() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_footer_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/customFooterStyle.css' );
} 
if(is_cart() || is_checkout() || is_account_page() ){
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'footerBarStyle');
}
```

Comment: Okay I gave this a shot and it did not work. The only thing that affects this is to directly change the storefronts woocommerce css in the assets/sass/woocommerce folders. Still trying a few options with this but no dice so far.